# Adding custom card on notification in Android Wearable

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

I'm actually setting a notification from my wearable.

The code of construction of this notification is actually this one :

```
int notificationId = 001;

Intent viewIntent = new Intent(this, Releves.class);
viewIntent.putExtra("My_Custom_Data_Key", "My_Custom_Data_Value");
PendingIntent viewPendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, viewIntent, 0);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Nouveaux Relevés")
                .setContentText("De nouveaux relevés sont disponibles")
                .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true);


NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);


notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
```

The resulting notification gives this behavior :

[image: Actual Notification]

I would like to enhance my notification and add a custom Page before "Open", like this :

[image]

Regarding the Android Developer Official site : https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/pages.html

It's possible to add pages to notification with a certain style (e.g : Big Text Style Notification).

I don't want a BigTextStyle notification, I would like to fully customize the notification pages (from the first to the last displayed).

1/ Is it possible to fully customize a notification page ?
2/ If so, how far can I customize the notification ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make fully customized notification.

This link may help you solve this problem.

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/layouts.html

Comment: This is for standalone apps not notifications.

Comment: Yeah, that is a standalone app. but you can put standalone activity on notification. when you put these option  android:exported="true"
     android:allowEmbedded="true"
     android:taskAffinity=""